# Customer export not working after creating custom attributes in magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, export, customer-grid

I have created a custom attribute named "Approve Account" while export getting below error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/tgbl222/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 220 and defined in /var/www/html/tgbl222/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:172 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/tgbl222/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(220): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('approve_account', NULL) #1 /var/www/html/tgbl222/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php(77): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('approve_account', 'int', Array) #2 /var/www/html/tgbl222/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php(184): Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column->prepare() #3 /var/www/html/tgbl222/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Component/MassAction/Filter/Interceptor.php(63): Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter->p in /var/www/html/tgbl222/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 172

**`/app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="customer_columns">
    <column name="approve_account">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Active</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">280</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

**`/app/code/Namespace/Module/setup/installData.php`**

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    /**
     *  Customer attributes
     */
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);


    /**
     * Create customer attribute account_approve
     */
    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, self::APPROVE_ACCOUNT,
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Approve Account',
            'input' => 'select',
            "source"   => "RBC\Customersegment\Model\Config\Source\CustomerYesNoOptions",
            'required' => false,
            'default' => '1',
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 215,
            'position' => 215,
            'system' => false,
        ]);
    $approve_account = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, self::APPROVE_ACCOUNT)
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit'],
        ]);
    $approve_account->save();

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: If you want to create YES/NO options for customer, then you need to used boolean attribute.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya thanks i was also tried with Boolean attribute still getting  issue while export customer. my question is there any missing or wrong code? why i am getting error while export customer.

Comment: Facing the same issue, let me know if you find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried the below code with **static** datatype but it has consequences as mentioned below:

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, self::APPROVE_ACCOUNT,
        [
            'type' => 'static',
            'label' => 'Approve Account',
            'input' => 'select',
            "source"   => "RBC\Customersegment\Model\Config\Source\CustomerYesNoOptions",
            'required' => false,
            'default' => '1',
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 215,
            'position' => 215,
            'system' => false,
        ]);
```

Using **static** datatype in attribute will solve the problem in grid export but will throw error while **reindexing** as the the attribute type is static, it will look into customer_entity table for this field which you might not have created. So in your case, you can follow the suggestions as mentioned below.

It seems that you have not created field in **customer_entity** table, you are using **attribute** here, so make sure you have not added field in **customer_listing** layout in **ui_component** directory. Also you don't have to add the field in **indexer.xml** as for attributes, it automatically updates data in **customer_grid_flat** table.

I hope this helps you with your problem.

Comment: Thanks man it working fine! :), you are right i was checked there is no attribute data type is int.

Comment: @Chirag: I have update my answer, the problem was not the datatype but the other things as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @ChiragPatel I do have the same issue , when i take the export csv this error occurs with my custom attributes, how can i solve this other than making static?