# Magento 2 customer export is giving me the error

Tags: magento2, customer, export

***I added one custom attribute with Yes/No option in customer grid and with that i'm unable to export the customer data, facing issue like below***

> Fatal error: Uncaught Type Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line
>   222 and defined in
>   vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:174

*When i tried to debug the column data Type is taking as int if it is select my export is working fine. For this attribute i'm using backed_type as int and fronted_input as Boolean. When I changed this back end type to static it is not displaying the customers in grid and SQL error is like unknown column.*

*If some one faced this issue, suggest me how can we do this.*

Comment: possible to setup basic commands, first possibility to put your basic commands.

Comment: I followed this link as this issue is same as mine https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241765/customer-export-not-working-after-creating-custom-attributes-in-magento-2-2-5 to resolve this issue but I'm loosing the filter option and when I update attribute backend type with static I'm loosing the field data as well.